# Pretty URL ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I get pretty urls like localhost:8888/News/Example-post instead of localhost:8888/Home/Details/2

My HomeController has the following for the Details method

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var ArticleToView = (from m in _db.ArticleSet where m.storyId == id select m).First();

    return View(ArticleToView);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the ASP.NET routing system is somewhat complicated, there are many ways to accomplish what you describe.

First of all, **do you just want to have a pretty URL for the Details method?** If so, you might consider renaming HomeController to NewsController or moving the Details method into a new NewsController class - that will automatically form the `/News` part of the URL. If you don't want a `/Details` part, you might rename your Details method `Index`, as that will be automatically called by `/News`. Finally, you need to change your `int id` parameter into `string name`.

**If you want many custom URLs, you're going to have to define your own routes.** Here are two ways of doing this:

1.
The easiest way I've found is to **use an [ASP.NET MVC Attribute-Based Route Mapper](http://maproutes.codeplex.com/)**. That way, all you have to do is add an attribute on each method you want a pretty URL for and specify what URL you want.

First, you must follow a few steps to set up the attribute-based route mapping system, as outlined on that link.
After completing those steps, you must change your method to look like this:

```
[Url("News/{name}")]
public ActionResult Details(string name)
{
    var ArticleToView = (from m in _db.ArticleSet where m.storyName == name select m).First();

    return View(ArticleToView);
}
```

2.
Alternatively, you can **define your custom routes manually in `Global.asax.cs`**. In your `RegisterRoutes` method, you can add the following in the middle:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "NewsDetails",                                                   
                "News/{name}",                                 
                new { controller = "News", action = "Details", name = "" }
            );
```

Comment: Isn't there a built-in way of doing this without requiring additional add-ons etc

Comment: @Cameron Sure there is: you can define routes in Global.asax just as easily, but I've found that using something like what I linked to is certainly worth the extra DLL.

Comment: What about just changing Home to News for all the methods within the HomeController?

Comment: Attribute based route mapping is awesome.  I wouldn't develop in ASP.Net MVC without it.

Answer (score 1):

What I do on my sites is that I check the URL against either the Page Title or Page Stub in cases where the page titles could have the same name for instance if you have a site that posts a "Picture of the Week" you may want to use a stub instead of title as you'll have multiples named the same thing.

URLs look like this: http://mySite.com/Page/Verse-of-the-Week

Global.asax contains this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Pages", "{controller}/{pageID}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", pageID = "Home" });
```

PageController is this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Index(string pageID)
    {
        if (pageID == null)
        {
            pageID = pageRepository.HomeOrLowest();
        }
        var p = pageRepository.ByStub(pageID);
        if (p == null) { return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error"); }
        return View(p);
    }
```

The repository looks like this:

```
    private static Func<mvCmsContext, string, Page> _byStub =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((mvCmsContext context, string pageTitle) =>
            (from p in context.Pages
             where p.pageTitle.Replace(" ", "-") == pageTitle
             select p).SingleOrDefault());
    public Page ByStub(string pageTitle)
    {
        return _byStub(context, pageTitle);
    }
```

I hope that helps.

Edit to add duplicate handling:

```
    private static Func<mvCmsContext, string, int> _pageExists =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((mvCmsContext context, string pageTitle) =>
            (from p in context.Pages
             where p.pageTitle.Replace(" ", "-") == pageTitle
             select p).Count());
    public bool PageExists(string pageTitle)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(_pageExists(context, pageTitle));
    }
```

Validates like this:

```
        IValidationErrors errors = new ValidationErrors();
        if (CreateOrEdit == "Create")
        {
            if (pageRepository.PageExists(model.pageTitle) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.pageTitle))
                errors.Add("pageTitle", "A page with this title already exists.  Please edit it and try again.");
        }
```

Comment: mark - can you explain a little more in detail how you mitigate duplicate page names please. i get the gist of what you're saying but am not clear as to how you completely remove the occurrence of duplicates (do you append the page id??). thanks..

Comment: It depends on the site.  On my personal site it throws ValidationErrors and request you rename the Page.  You could just as easily append (or prepend) a number or a DateTime then run it through again and increment if necessary.  Edited post to include PageExists check.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this package I've created: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseDashedRoute/
And read the one-line configuration here: https://github.com/AtaS/lowercase-dashed-route