# How to create a short URL for public profile page

Tags: redirect

how can i create a url for public profile page like this type
www.mywebsite/myname
and this url redirect me to may public profile page in mywebsite
where actual url may be of this type
www.ywebsite/user/publicProfile?uid=12  etc

Comment: You don't say which web server, which OS, which software development platform, etc.  Is this a programming question?  If not, you should visit a forum for webmasters.

Comment: have a look here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610610/pretty-url-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet would be to go with ASP.NET routing.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Although to get where you could use a username instead of an ID in the URL you would have to do some additional querying behind on the page that has the public profile to get the appropriate ID for the specific user name.

Comment: This would only be the "best bet" if the questioner is using ASP.NET and IIS.  We don't know what the platform is.

Comment: It was originally tagged with C# but the tags were removed for some reason.  So I had assumed ASP.NET and IIS.